# pass quoted arguments to azure webapp for containers --startup-file

Tags: r, azure, docker, azure-webapps, azure-web-app-for-containers

For an [Azure Web App for Containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/containers/) I need to pass a quoted [`az webapp config set --startup-file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-set).
For example, the argument needs to include **spaces**.

#### TL; DR

- This really *should* work, because `--startup-file` just gets appended to `docker run` as a docker `[COMMAND]` would be.
- **Nested quoting** (i.e. `--startup-file "Rscript -e '1+1'"`), weirdly, leads to weird **double quoting** of the inner quotes (R receives the `[EXPR]` as a string `[1] "1+1"`).
- Anything with spaces, quoted or not, **gets broken up** into separate arguments to `Rscript` (or `docker run`?) and thus fails.

It's unclear to me what quoting Azure does on the backend with the `--startup-file`, because the logged `docker run`s all look fine.
On the one hand, Azure seems to quote *too much* (leading to strings), but on the other hand not enough (because spaces still break stuff up).

---

#### Background

I'm assuming that `--startup-file` *can* in fact accommodate arbitrary shell commands (not just executable files), because:

1. It is variously described as "Startup *Command*" and "Startup *File*" on `portal.azure.com`.
2. As per the logs, it just gets appended to `docker run` as `[COMMAND]` and should thus adhere to the same semantics.
3. It *works* (unless there's spaces).

I'm aware that the underlying problem is that shell arguments are space-separated, but, as is shown below, simple `"` don't do it.

I'm using `Rscript -e "1 + 1"` as an example here because a) R is my use case and b) it's easy to see what goes wrong.
[`Rscript`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html) is a binary to batch process R, with semantics similar to, say `sh -c "pwd;ls"`.
I am guessing that a similar reproducible example could be written for `sh -c`-type startup files.

None of the examples below will start an http server and thus fail the `az webapp restart`, but with container logging enabled, it's easy to see what is *already* going wrong.
(The actual use case would be `Rscript -e "shiny::runApp()"` which *will* start an http server.)

#### Baseline

As a baseline, this is the corresponding `docker run`, which works just fine locally (macOS 10.15.6, Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe):

```sh
docker run rstudio/r-base:4.0.2-xenial Rscript -e "1 + 1"
# [1] 2
# works as expected
```

#### Nested Quotes

```sh
az webapp config set --name hello-shiny \
  --startup-file "Rscript -e \"1+2\""
```

```sh
az webapp config set --name hello-shiny \
  --startup-file 'Rscript -e "1+3"'
```

```sh
az webapp config set --name hello-shiny \
  --startup-file "Rscript -e '1+4'"
```

The corresponding `docker run` for each of the above, as per the Azure logs is something like:

```
docker run -d -p 8409:3838 \
  -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true \
  -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=hello-shiny \
  -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False \
  -e PORT=3838 \ 
  -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 \
  -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=hello-shiny.azurewebsites.net \ 
  -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 \
  rocker/shiny:4.0.2 \
  Rscript -e "1+2"
```

(I've dropped some `-e`s).
This is, as noted, a valid `docker run` call.
If run locally (see above) it yields, as expected:

```
# [1] 3
```

But on Azure, you get the argument *as a character string* in R, like the below for each of the variants

```r
# [1] "1+2"
```

This is weird, because it suggests that azure somehow has surrounded the argument with *another* set of quotes.
To reproduce it locally, you'd need to run

```sh
docker run rstudio/r-base:4.0.2-xenial Rscript -e "'1+1'"
# [1] "1+1"
```

Clearly not what I want, and (I think?) undocumented azure behavior.

#### No Quotes, No Spaces (Works!)

Sure enough then, passing the argument *without* quotes (and spaces) works:

```sh
az webapp config set --name hello-shiny \
  --startup-file "Rscript -e 1+7"
```

Yields `[1] 8`.

This not surprising, because both

- `docker run rstudio/r-base:4.0.2-xenial Rscript -e "1+1"` *and*
- `docker run rstudio/r-base:4.0.2-xenial Rscript -e 1+1` work,

because the customary quoting of `-e [EXPR]` is unnecessary here.

But not using spaces, while technically possible here, isn't really a solution.

#### Spaces, No Quotes (Broken)

```sh
az webapp config set --name hello-shiny \
  --startup-file "Rscript -e 1 + 8"
```

Yields just `[1] 1` on Azure, as expected, because `docker run` will just treat everything after `1` as a separate argument, and thus ignore it.

#### Spaces, All Sorts of Quoting (All Broken)

So, no problem, one might think, I'm going to escape this some more.

```sh
az webapp config set --name hello-shiny \
  --startup-file "Rscript -e '1 + 5'"
```

```sh
az webapp config set --name hello-shiny \
  --startup-file "Rscript -e \"1 + 6\""
```

These, and their sad friends, all yield:

```
# Error: unexpected end of input
# Execution halted
```

That's a bit weird, because it means that somehow *part* of the R code (up to, and including `+`) makes it, though not the crucial `5`.

The only way I can think to reproduce this is by running

```sh
docker run rstudio/r-base:4.0.2-xenial Rscript -e "1 +" 7
# Error: unexpected end of input
# Execution halted
```

---

#### What's going on here?

I absolutely cannot make heads nor tails of whatever quoting/escaping Azure is doing here.
I'm either, very, very dense (likely), or Azure does something super weird and undocumented (possible?).

**How can I pass an argument with spaces as a `--startup-file` to Azure?**

Ps.: I'm aware I can avoid all of these shenanigans by just adding corresponding `CMD` instruction to my `Dockerfile` and leaving `--startup-file` blank, but a) that would be cumbersome for simple options and b) it's *gotta be possible*.

Comment: Azure Support has graciously provided a free ticket, under which this is currently being investigated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official document to explain how does the parameter `--startup-file` work and the limitation. I only can give you an opinion of my own.

First, the parameter needs a string value, you can get the description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdateconfiguration#request-body) about the property `appCommandLine`. At this time, maybe it only works for the string without quotes. And then it comes to the command for the image. You give the command `Rscript` parameters `-e 1+7`. In docker command, you put them in the quotes like `"1 + 7"`, but when the quotes go away, it should be `1+7`, without spaces. So finally, the value for the parameter `--startup-file` is `"Rscript -e 1+7"`.

It's just my personal opinion, for reference only.

Comment: thanks for chiming in; passing the argument without spaces is my hack-fix, too, as mentioned, but I don't think it's a proper solution.

Comment: @maxheld You can feedback, but now it's designed as it does. You only follow it.

Comment: @maxheld Any idea or questions?